# Repeating the nested objects of a single element with angular

Tags: angularjs, oop

Most of the answers I've found are for repeating the entire object, and that works for me without problem. What I need is to display the objects of an element in an array. Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('QLoad', []);
app.controller('loadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.question=[
  {Id:'1', qText:'What\'s your Gender?',aCollection:[
      {text:'Male', 
      icon:'fa fa-male fa-5x'},
      {text:'Female', 
      icon:"fa fa-female fa-5x"}
      ]
  },
  {Id:'2', qText:'What kind of Pain do you have?',aCollection:[
      {text:'Burning', 
      icon:'fa fa-fire fa-5x'},
      {text:'Stinging', 
      icon:"fa-bee.png"}
      ]
    }];

});
```

As I mentioned, I could easily do two nested ng-repeats and display everything, but I only need to display the answers for each individual question. That's why I have the following two views I've tried, but it neither works:

```
<h1>{{question[0].qText}}</h1>
<div  ng-repeat="q in question">
    <div ng-repeat="answer in q.aCollection" class="content">
      <div class=button>
      <i class="{{q[0].answer.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      {{q[0].answer.text}}
      </div>
    </div></div>
```

Nor does this work:

```
    <h1>{{question[0].qText}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question[0].aCollection" class="content">
              <div class=button>
              <i class="{{answer.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              {{answer.text}}
              </div>
            </div></div>
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I can't display a single question object and its nested array. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can not fully understand what you are trying to do here. I made a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dVeUTOSvhVvk2R6aiQsW?p=preview) taking your code and it seems working fine. Can you please explain more?

Comment: The result should look like:
<h1>What's your Gender?</h1>
<div>
<div> (Male Icon) Male</div>
<div> (Female Icon) Female</div>
</div>

With the two views I have I either only get the header only, or the header and ALL answers including the ones for the next question (ie buring, stinging,..)

Comment: I am still in confusion with your requirements. The thing I understood so far is that you don't want to show all questions at a time. Instead you want to show questions one by one. Am I right?

Comment: That's exactly right. I need to show only one question ever. I will be using an onclick directive to scroll through the question array, but the page should only ever show one single question and answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[limitTo][1]` filter to achieve that.

```
<div  ng-repeat="q in question | limitTo:1">
    <div ng-repeat="answer in q.aCollection" class="content">
      <div class=button>
      <i class="{{answer.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      {{answer.text}}
      </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: In this case how do I control which question will show up? For example, if I have thirty questions, how do I specify question[0] or question[27]

Answer (score 0):

One of solution maybe is

```
   <div  ng-repeat="q in question">
      <div ng-click="a($index)">{{q.qText}}</div>
    </div>
    <h1>{{answ.text}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in answ.answerList" class="content">
      <div class=button>
      <i class="{{answer.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      {{answer.text}}
    </div>
```

and your controller look like

```
$scope.answ = {};
$scope.answ.text = $scope.question[0].qText
$scope.answ.answerList = $scope.question[0].aCollection;
$scope.a = function(index){
   $scope.answ.text = $scope.question[index].qText
$scope.answ.answerList = $scope.question[index].aCollection;
}
```

Example you can see on [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mySvJooCoqXiR76y4An0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an index which will be incremented with the ng-click.

**Template**

```
<h1>{{question[questionTrackIndex].qText}}</h1>
<div ng-repeat="answer in question[questionTrackIndex].aCollection" class="content">
    <div class=button>
        <i class="{{answer.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{answer.text}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="btn btn-warning" ng-if="questionTrackIndex != 0" ng-click="previousQuestion()">Previous</div>
<div class="btn btn-warning" ng-if="question.length - 1 > questionTrackIndex" ng-click="nextQuestion()">Next</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.questionTrackIndex = 0;

$scope.question=[
    {Id:'1', qText:'What\'s your Gender?',aCollection:[
        {text:'Male', 
        icon:'fa fa-male fa-5x'},
        {text:'Female', 
        icon:"fa fa-female fa-5x"}
        ]
    },
    {Id:'2', qText:'What kind of Pain do you have?',aCollection:[
        {text:'Burning', 
        icon:'fa fa-fire fa-5x'},
        {text:'Stinging', 
        icon:"fa-bee.png"}
        ]
    },
    {Id:'3', qText:'Question no 3',aCollection:[
        {text:'Answer1', 
        icon:'fa fa-fire fa-5x'},
        {text:'Answer2', 
        icon:"fa-bee.png"}
        ]
    }
  ];

$scope.nextQuestion = function() {
  $scope.questionTrackIndex++;
}

$scope.previousQuestion = function() {
  $scope.questionTrackIndex--;
}
```

The variable `$scope.questionTrackIndex` has been used to scroll through the questions. I have added two buttons `next` and `previous` to scroll through the questions. With clicking `next` button, `$scope.questionTrackIndex` has been incremented and with clicking `previous` button, `$scope.questionTrackIndex` has been decremented.

See this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/FQRXJ8E5o9AcCWYFsBoR?p=preview)